# Error al recibir un Extra de un intent desde MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo un incoveniente al pasar los datos de un intent a otro, tengo un login el cual depende de si el usuario ya tiene informacion almacenada de si mismo abre un nuevo intent, pero cuando esa informacion es recibida por el extra del MainActivity no entra a el try-catch de mi metodo para sacar el nombre de la tabla, pero si es mandada desde mi formulario para guardar los datos del nuevo usuario, si entra a el try-catch

```
if(intent==3)
        {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("as","as");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DoctorMain.class);
            intent.putExtra("doctorIdUser", id_usuario);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        if(intent==4)
        {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("as","as");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FormularioDoctorActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("doctorIdUser", id_usuario);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
```

Aqui es donde necesito recibir el extra

```
Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if(parametros !=null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(DoctorMain.this, parametros.getString("doctorIdUser"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try{
            Toast.makeText(DoctorMain.this, db_doctor.nombreDoctor(parametros.getString("doctorIdUser")), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            textoNombre.setText(db_doctor.nombreDoctor(parametros.getString("doctorIdUser")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            textoNombre.setText("NoEntroAlTryCatch");
        }
    }
    else
        textoNombre.setText("NoTieneDatosElItnent");
```

ALGO MAS ENTENDIBLE
Tengo el login, y ahi se puede registrar el usuario o entrar con un usuario ya existente, si es nuevo usuario abre un formulario para llenar sus datos y despues ya abre la vista de doctor y jala el idUsuario mediante un extra, y en la pantalla de vista de doctor entra a un metodo con argumento idUsuario y saca el nombre del doctor y lo pone en la cabecera
Pero si ya esa el usuario registrado y tiene sus datos pues se pasa directo del login a la ventana de doctor, y desde ahi mando el extra con el idUsuario para igual, recibirlo y mediante un metodo que recibe el idUsuario debe sacar el nombre, pero cuando lo mando directo desde el login no entra al metodo, pero si lo mando desde el formulario si entra al metodo, Pero si recibe los extras, mas si lo recibe desde el login no entra al metodo, si lo recibe desde el formulario si entra al metodo

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Creo que te enredas demasiado en tus explicaciones (y también en tu código, el cual es muy repetitivo, luego si quieres te indicaremos una forma de simplificar). Lo principal ahora es que nos expliques bien qué es lo que no funciona y dónde es que no funciona. Entre que si el login y el no login te enredas de tal modo que no se entiende nada. Dinos: _aquí no me funciona_. Y, otra cosa, ¿probaste que le estás pasando datos realmente? ¿Probaste a pasarle un dato escrito a mano? A veces son las variables las que están vacías y crees que le estás pasando algo.

Answer (score -1):

El problema es en la fuente de datos.
tu variable id_usuario es un String o es un TexView .?

Si es un Texview ese seria el inconveniente ya que no estas obteniendo ningun valor de esa manera.

Intenta de nuevo con este código.

```
            Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this, DoctorMain.class);
            i.putExtra("id_usuario ",id_usuario.getText().toString().trim());
            startActivity(i);
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score -1):

Estoy un poco confuso con la pregunta y el código.

Esta línea de código `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FormularioDoctorActivity.class);` ¿no está abriendo el formulario de registro? Si es así, entonces en el código de ejemplo falta ver cómo estás pasando del formulario de registro a la actividad principal, que entiendo que es el que sí funciona.

Por otro lado, ¿puedes indicarnos cual es el resultado desde el login? Es decir: Entiendo que desde el formulario de registro entras al `try` y lo hace bien y te pone el nombre del doctor, pero desde el login, qué pone, ¿lo del `else`? ¿o lo del `catch`? ¿Si es lo del `catch` puedes ponernos el texto de error que da?

Si puedes editar tu pregunta con algunas respuestas a esto, puedo editar mi respuesta si veo como ayudarte.